# Express Route Regex Match With Question Mark

Tags: regex, express

I've been trying to match the following URL:

> http://localhost:3000/?uid=Nf83K3L

with `app.get(/^\/\?uid.+/, userController.redirectUid)` but it's not working.

I've tried to escape the question mark with \? as well, but still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong, or am I not allowed to match question marks in express routes?

Comment: Is it possible to match the `?key=value&key=value` syntax either the `/key/value/key/value` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the carat(^) as it means `/` should be the beginning of the string you want to match.

```
app.get(/\/\?uid.+/, userController.redirectUid).
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: It still didn't work for me as it wasn't a regex issue apparently, but just the way Express works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why app.get didn't work, but managed to solve it with app.use and matching it to the req.OriginalUrl.

Working code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.match(/^\/\?uid.+/)) {
    res.redirect('/uid') //I just redirected directly without calling the middleware
  }
}
```